# Strategies for swapping the order of integration with dependent bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

What are the general strategies for swapping the order of integration given dependent bounds?  Specifically, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, Fubini's theorem allows us the following
$$
     \int_{a}^b\int_{c}^d f(x,y) dy dx= \int_c^d\int_a^b f(x,y) dx dy
$$
However, if we have a dependent bound, such as the integral
$$
     \int_a^b\int_{c(x)}^{d(x)} f(x,y) dy dx
$$
the exchange of integrals isn't so simple.  Sometimes, we can fiddle with things algebraically, but I'm interested if there's a general strategy for doing so (some sort of change of variables trick?).  More generally, I'm interested in the measure theoretic case where we have
$$
     \int_A\int_{B(x)} f(x,y) \mu(dy) \lambda(dx)
$$
and $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are measures.  Basically, I'd like to be able to write this as
$$
     \int_{B}\int_{A(y)} f(x,y) \lambda(dx) \mu(dy)
$$
or something similar.